# Time thread just stops after a while

Tags: c#, .net

I have a timer in C# (`System.Threading.Timer`) which runs great and after a while it's thread just disappears...

No exceptions have been caught and the reference to the timer is not lost (it's therefore not collected by the GC)

Is there anything that else else which could cause this?

(I can't post the code here)

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: 1. Give some code to understand what is going on. 2. Check if you enable unhandled exception handling in VS: Debug-> Exceptions.

Comment: just an addition to @Tigran post: to catch unhandled exceptions, adjust the VS as follows: 1)  Go to the Debug-->Exceptions dialog and check the Common Language Runtime Exceptions and check the checkbox in the Thrown column;
2)  Go to the Tools-->Options-->Debugging and uncheck the Enable Just My Code (Managed Only) checkbox.  Do you see the exception?

Comment: How are you using `Timer` that it requires a dedicated thread? (The first paragraph of the remarks of [`Timer`'s doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) says the callback is *always* run in the thread pool.)

Answer (score 2):

Even if your code inside callback is perfectly valid someone may incorrectly works with ThreadPool threads in your project and System.Threading.Timer uses ThreadPool threads to handle their callback, therefore, you simply may run out of free threads to handle timer callbacks.